# Reversing Characters within a List using a loop

Tags: python

This is my code I have come up with trying to reverse these strings

```
presidents = [ "George Washington " , " John Adams " , " Thomas Jefferson " , " James Madison " , " James Monroe " ," John Quincy Adams " ]

reversedPresidents=""
for ch in presidents:
    reversedPresidents=ch+reversedPresidents

print(reversedPresidents)
```

As of now, it only prints the list backwards like this:

```
John Quincy Adams  James Monroe  James Madison  Thomas Jefferson  John Adams George Washington
```

I need it to output the list like:

```
notgnihsaW egroeG
smadA nhoJ
```

and so on

Comment: Change `ch` to `ch[::-1]` and then `+reversedPresidents` in the loop.

Comment: The reason it prints the list backwards is because you are reversing the list and not the characters.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reverse a string in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/931092/reverse-a-string-in-python)

Comment: What's with the torrential flood of downvotes? Please explain them in the comments.

Comment: @Sebastian it's a blatant duplicate with no attempt at solving the problem.

Comment: That's fair, but there were 6 downvotes with only one comment about possible issues.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
>>> reversedPresidents = [p[::-1] for p in presidents]
>>> print(reversedPresidents)
[' notgnihsaW egroeG', ' smadA nhoJ ', ' nosreffeJ samohT ', ' nosidaM semaJ ', ' eornoM semaJ ', ' smadA ycniuQ nhoJ ']
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

Beauty of Recursion :

```
presidents = [ "George Washington " , " John Adams " , " Thomas Jefferson " , " James Madison " , " James Monroe " ," John Quincy Adams " ]

def reverse_list(list_1):
    for item in list_1:
        def reverse(word):
            if len(word)==0:
                return word
            else:
                return reverse(word[1:]) + word[0]
        print(reverse(item))
print(reverse_list(presidents))
```

output:

```
 notgnihsaW egroeG
 smadA nhoJ 
 nosreffeJ samohT 
 nosidaM semaJ 
 eornoM semaJ 
 smadA ycniuQ nhoJ
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this also:

```
>>> presidents = [ "George Washington " , " John Adams " , " Thomas Jefferson " , " James Madison " , " James Monroe " ," John Quincy Adams " ]

>>>> print(["".join(reversed(x)) for x in presidents])
[' notgnihsaW egroeG', ' smadA nhoJ ', ' nosreffeJ samohT ', ' nosidaM semaJ ', ' eornoM semaJ ', ' smadA ycniuQ nhoJ ']
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
presidents = [ "George Washington " , " John Adams " , " Thomas Jefferson " , 
" James Madison " , " James Monroe " ," John Quincy Adams " ]

reversedPresidents=[]
for ch in presidents: 
     reversedPresidents.append(ch[::-1])

print(reversedPresidents)

 [' notgnihsaW egroeG', ' smadA nhoJ ', ' nosreffeJ samohT ', ' nosidaM 
  semaJ ', ' eornoM semaJ ', ' smadA ycniuQ nhoJ ']
```